# NASM mixed string in output

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, nasm

I'm trying to make a simple "create file with prompt" code from the tutorial I fetched here [Assembly - File Management](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_file_management.htm). But everytime I input something, the output strings in the terminal will be mixed and cut together. And the file that would be created is mixed too.

Code is here:

```
    section .data
Msg1: db 'Masukkan nama Anda ',0xa
Msg1ln equ $-Msg1

Name: db ' ', 0xa               ; space characters

msg_done: db 'File telah dibuat ', 0xa
;msg_doneln equ $-msg_done


section .text
   global _start         

_start:                  

   ; Output  'Masukkan nama Anda '
mov eax, 4              ; write…
mov ebx, 1              ; to the standard output (screen/console)…
mov ecx, Msg1           ; the information at memory address prompt
mov edx, Msg1ln         ; 19 bytes (characters) of that information
int 0x80                ; invoke an interrupt

; Accept input and store the user’s name
mov eax, 3              ; read…
mov ebx, 1              ; from the standard input (keyboard/console)…
mov ecx, Name               ; storing at memory location name…
mov edx, 23                 ; 23 bytes (characters) is ok for my name
int 0x80

   ;create the file
   mov  eax, 8
   mov  ebx, Name
   mov  ecx, 0777        ;read, write and execute by all
   int  0x80             ;call kernel

   mov [fd_out], eax

    ;write the message indicating end of file write
   mov eax, 4
   mov ebx, 1
   mov ecx, msg_done
   mov edx, 18
   int  0x80

   mov  [fd_in], eax


   mov  eax,1             ;system call number (sys_exit)
   int  0x80              ;call kernel

section .bss
fd_out resb 1
fd_in  resb 1
```

The terminal is like this if I input "Jack"

```
Masukkan nama Anda
Jack
ck
e telah dibuat
```

How it should be

```
Masukkan nama Anda
Jack 
File telah dibuat
```

And the file name is

```
Jack e telah dibuat
```

How it should be

```
Jack
```

Sorry, I'm new to the Assembly.
Now I'm still trying editing around the eax,ebx things. Will post if I know something. 
Great thanks!

**Update**
It looks like I was using 32bit code for 64bit assembly. So I changed most of the syntax (But the problem is not this). Final code worked (thanks to that guy on the bottom).

```
section .data
Msg1: db 'Masukkan nama Anda',0xa
Msg1ln equ $-Msg1

Name: times 23 db ' ',0

msg_done: db 'File telah dibuat ', 0xa
;msg_doneln equ $-msg_done

fd dq 0

section .text
global _start         

_start:                  

; Output  'Masukkan nama Anda '
mov rax, 1              ; write…
mov rdi, 0              ; to the standard output (screen/console)…
mov rsi, Msg1           ; the information at memory address prompt
mov rdx, Msg1ln         ; 19 bytes (characters) of that information
syscall                 ; Interrupt buat 64bit Linux adalah syscall, sedangkan 32bit int 0x80

; Accept input and store the user’s name
mov rax, 0              ; read…
mov rdi, 1              ; from the standard input (keyboard/console)…
mov rsi, Name               ; storing at memory location name…
mov rdx, 23                 ; 23 bytes (characters) is ok for my name
syscall

;create the file
mov  rax, 85
mov  rdi, Name
mov rsi,777o                ;Permission tipe data oktal -rwxrwxrwx
syscall

mov [fd], rax

;write the message indicating end of file write
mov rax, 1
mov rdi, 1
mov rsi, msg_done
mov rdx, 18
syscall

mov  [fd], rax


mov    rax, 60
mov    rdi, 0
syscall
```

Comment: You only allocated enough for a single character at `Name`. You need more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your memory layout is like this

```
..., ' ', 0xA, 'F', 'i', 'l', 'e', ' ', 't', 'e', ...
```

Where `Name` points to the first `' '` and `msg_done` points to the `'F'`.

Once you store 23 bytes with that read at the address specified by `Name`, the place where `msg_done` points to get overwritten with that data as well since `Name` "has" only 2 bytes.

To correct your issue, you can use this, assuming your max length will stay at 23 chracters - it basically says "define 23 bytes initialized to `' '` at this location that will also be reachable via `Name`"

```
Name: times 23 db ' '
```

Comment: That just worked for the rest problem! But, I don't understand your last line. It still write  msg_done into output file (file name merged)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, that part of answer was incorrect with respect to your code. I have removed it. Your null-terminator added behind `Name` that never gets overwritten solves the issue.